# How can I add Applicasas SDK to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to add Applicasas SDK to Android Studio. Applicasas Start guide just covers Eclipse http://doc.applicasa.com/docs/content/android/#getting-started, and I have read it multiple times, but I cant get it to work in Android Studio.

I can add other SDKs without problem, for example facebooks, but I cant get Applicasas to work. Could somebody please explain to me how to add Applicasas SDK to android studio, or at least point me in the in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: If I try to add the sdk I get this error:
 `Gradle 'myApp' project refresh failed: Configuration with name 'default' not found.`

[image]

I got help to import one image in my post, thank you! Here are the second image showing more of the structure of the SDK https://i.stack.imgur.com/nINg2.png . You are very welcome to import the link as a image to.

My settings.gradle

```
include ':myApp'
include ':libs:facebook'
include ':libs:ApplicasaSDK'
include ':libs'
```

My build.gradle

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile project(':libs:facebook')
compile project(':libs:ApplicasaSDK')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
}
```

As you can see in my .gradles I have also added a facebook sdk, and the facebook sdk works perfekt, but I dont know what to do with the Applicasa SDK.

I am very thankful for all the help I can get!

Comment: Which error is Android Studio giving to you?

Comment: @Narkha Thank you for your comment! I have updated my question with more information. Here are the second image I couldn't post: http://i.imgur.com/tzzhWuG.png?1?2324

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to set up a build.gradle build file for ApplicasaSDK; it seems like it doesn't have one. You get this "Configuration with name 'default' not found" error when Gradle is trying to build a module and it either doesn't find a build file at all or there are very serious problems with it.